# How can this regex by improved? It's hitting the PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR for PHP on very short text

Tags: php, regex

The following regex:

```
$common_tlds = 'us|me|com|net|org|ly|be|edu|gov|uk|ca|de|jp|fr|au|ru|ch|it|nl|se|no|es|mil|co';

$regex = '#(?:https?://)?([^.\s]+(?:[^\s.]|[^\s][^\s.])*\.(?:' . $common_tlds . ')[^.\s]*)#i';
```

used here:

```
preg_replace($regex,'<a href="http://$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $text);
```

Is giving me a `PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR` on very short text. One example text is:

`Life cant always give you the best shoes,handbags,clothes but it can give you the best creations.`

I know, there are better link finding regex online, but I was curious about what in my regex was causing massive backtracking and how I could improve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$regex = '#(?:https?://)?([^.\s]+(?:\.[^.\s]+)*\.(?:' . $common_tlds . '))#i';
```

Comments:

- You are seeing [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) - your pattern has too many ways to fail matching the string.
- `[^.\s]+(?:\.[^.\s]+)*` allows only one way of matching the domain, anchoring at dots.
- `[^.\s]*` - Removed from the end, not sure what it suppose to do after the tld. If you want to match domains like `.co.il`, you may want another dot there: `(?:\.[^.\s]+)?`
- You may want a `\b` at the start, to avoid matching `(google.com`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The `[^.\s]*` at the end is to match the rest of the link. e.g. `example.com/abc?x=y`.